# is_int Function returns string In PHP

Tags: php

I am using [is_int function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) To check Whether The Value i get is int or not
My code is

```
<?php

$a = 3;

if(is_int($a)){
    echo "INT";
}else{
    echo "STRINIG";
}
```

Which returns me **INT**
But When it tried Using This code

```
<?php

$a = "3";

if(is_int($a)){
    echo "INT";
}else{
    echo "STRINIG";
}
```

It returns me sting .

So why this happen ?

**UPDATE**

I have problem in following code
Let Suppose i have array As

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => xxxx )
```

now i have to fetch String So i do

```
foreach ($mypreferdservice as $value) {
  if(is_int($value)){
    echo "Int<br>";
  }else{
    echo "String";
  }
}
```

So it returns me string So How to solve this problem

Comment: well, the function is checking the type of variable. and as `$a` variable assigned with a string value, its type is `string`.

Comment: But how can Only Double Quote(")  Change Variable Type ?

Comment: `"3"` is a string while `3` is a int.

Comment: PHP is dynamically typed language, meaning that type of variable defined by its content. Going deeper in the memory `3` and `"3"` even represented differently. If you read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php): "To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric()."

Comment: @WebInfos, That's how string type works in dynamic type language. You can set any type value to a variable.

Comment: I have Updated Question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want check if the value is numeric, then `is_numeric`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) may be what your after -

```
$a = "3";

if(is_int($a)){
    echo "INT";
}else{
    echo "STRINIG";
}
if(is_numeric($a)){
    echo "INT";
}else{
    echo "STRINIG";
}
```

`is_int` checks the type of a field, `is_numeric` checks the value.

This outputs (not formatted very well)...

```
STRINIGINT
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything surrounded by `"` or `'` is string typed. That's why `is_int` function returning false.

> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes (the character ').
>
> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret the following escape sequences for special characters:

[php.net wiki on string type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

To get an idea how php data types work, read on
[php data types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if a string is an integer number then `is_int` or `is_numeric` alone won't cut it:

```
function is_integer_numeric($string) {
           return is_numeric($string) && is_int($string + 0); // Adding 0 to a numeric will cast it to either a float or int depending on what it really is.
}


var_dump(is_integer_numeric(3)); // true 
var_dump(is_integer_numeric("3")); // true
var_dump(is_integer_numeric("3.1")); // false
var_dump(is_integer_numeric(3.1));  // false
var_dump(is_integer_numeric("test"));  // false
```